# Sonata admin "sonata_type_collection" tries to remove entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have two entities and two Admin classes(StripePage and Stripe) for them. Form looks good, it has my fields and button to add new subforms. When "add new" button is clicked, new subform with form from Admin class is rendered, but if you click second time on this button or try to save entity error appears:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Fred\CoreBundle\Entity\StripePage::removeStripe() must be an instance
>   of Fred\CoreBundle\Entity\Stripe, null given in
>   C:\Users\lubimov\OpenServer\domains\tappic.dev\src\Fred\CoreBundle\Entity\StripePage.php

So symfony tries to remove entity instead of adding it.

StripePageAdmin class:

```
class StripePageAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id', null, array('label' => 'id'))
            ->add('name', null, array('label' => 'Page name'));
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Page name'))
            ->add('stripes', 'sonata_type_collection',
                array('label' => 'Stripes', 'required' => false, 'by_reference' => false),
                array('edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'table', 'sortable' => 'pos')
            )
            ->end();
    }
}
```

StripeAdmin class:

```
class StripeAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier('id')
            ->add('picture', null, array('sortable' => true))
            ->add('text', null, array('sortable' => true))
            ->add('deep_link', null, array('sortable' => true));
    }

    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('file', 'file', array('label' => 'Picture'))
            ->add('text', null, array('label' => 'Text'))
            ->add('deep_link', 'choice', array(
                'choices'  => array('test1' => 'Test1', 'test' => 'Test2'),
                'label' => 'Deep Link',
            ))
            ->end();
    }
}
```

What is the problem? Stripe form in admin class must be configured by other way?

Answer (score 0):

Well, solution that I use now is to set `'by_reference' => true` in 'sonata_type_collection' settings.

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Page name'))
        ->add('stripes', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array('label' => 'Stripes', 'required' => false, 'by_reference' => true),
            array('edit' => 'inline', 'inline' => 'table', 'sortable' => 'pos')
        )
        ->end();
}
```

After this need to declare `setStripes()` method in entity.

```
public function setStripes(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $stripes) {
    $this->stripes = $stripes;
}
```

If somebody finds how to solve this using `addStripe()` type of methods, please share it here.